# Trying to fetch data while using room and networkboundresource class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, dagger-2

I'm trying to fetch data from Tmdb and i'm using room  , dagger2 and networkboundresource class but the data not displayed and the logcat didn't show me any error .. i think i'm calling the wrong method in viewmodel or what

```
 fun loadMovies(page: Int = 1): LiveData<Resource<List<Movie>>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Movie>, MoviesResponse>(appExecutors) {
        // ignore
        override fun saveCallResult(item: MoviesResponse) {

        }

        override fun shouldFetch(data: List<Movie>?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<List<Movie>> {
           return moviesDao.getAllMovies()
        }

        override fun createCall(): LiveData<GenericApiResponse<MoviesResponse>> {
            return tmdbApi.getListMovies(page = page)
        }

    }.asLiveData()
```

and this my viewmodel

```
    class MainViewModel
@Inject
constructor(
   private val mainRepository: MainRepository
): ViewModel() {

    fun getPopularMovies(){
        mainRepository.loadMovies()
    }



}
```

model class

```
    @Entity(tableName = "Movies")
data class Movie(


    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    val title: String,

    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "overview")
    val overview: String,


    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "posterPath")
    val posterPath: String,
```

Comment: I am facing same issue with NetworkBoundResource, not getting the response. If you resolved the issue please answer here.